# Is it possible to add a datetime column to a manytomany field?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, django-models

I was wondering if there was a way to add a datetime auto_now_add=True column to a manytomany field.
I have the following model.

```
class Photographer(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
     bio = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
     favorites = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', through='Favorites', related_name = 'photographer_favs')
     likes = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', related_name='likedby', blank=True)
```

In my postgresql database, I have a separate table for likes called "djangoapp_*photographer*_likes".

In this table, I have three columns:

```
id                 photographer_id        photo_id
[PK] serial        integer                integer
    1                  3                    6
    2                  3                    7
    3                  3                    8
```

After several months of going into production, I realized that I would require the datetime of when these photos we're liked. So instead of three columns I would have four:

```
    id             photographer_id        photo_id      liked
[PK] serial        integer                integer       timestamp with time zone
    1                  3                    6           2013-07-10 23:30:19.559463+00
    2                  3                    7           2013-07-11 17:00:53.39614+00
    3                  3                    8           2013-07-11 17:25:28.4953+00
```

Is it possible to add this extra column even though it is not in the models? I want it so that every time a picture is liked, the time at which it is liked is recorded. If this is not possible, what other work arounds should I look into?

**EDIT**

This is my Photo model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
     photographer = models.ForeignKey(Photographer, related_name = 'shot_owner')
     postTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
     url = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Comment: It's very common for a relationship table (that resolves a many-to-many relationship between two entity tables) to have attributes. We just want to make sure the attribute is an attribute of the relationship, and not of one of the entities, or not itself an entity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.  You'll declare an explicit model for the Likes relationship and add the datetime field on it.  Check the [many-to-many field docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for full details and some examples - the group membership example includes a 'date joined' field that's the same idea as your like timestamp.  Using `auto_now_add=True` in the field's definition should automate the recording of the timestamp.

```
class Photographer(models.Model):
    # as above, but:
    likes = models.ManyToManyField('Photo', through='PhotoLikes', related_name='likedby', blank=True)

class PhotoLikes(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'djangoapp_photographer_likes'
        # or whatever your table is called
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    photographer = models.ForeignKey(Photographer)
    liked = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

As the docs note, the methods to create likes are a bit more restricted with this setup:

> Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can’t use add, create, or assignment (i.e., beatles.members = [...]) to create relationships
>
> Why? You can’t just create a relationship between a Person and a Group - you need to specify all the detail for the relationship required by the Membership model. The simple add, create and assignment calls don’t provide a way to specify this extra detail. As a result, they are disabled for many-to-many relationships that use an intermediate model. The only way to create this type of relationship is to create instances of the intermediate model.

In this case, it would theoretically be possible to determine the additional detail, since it's an automatic timestamp, but Django isn't quite able to detect that.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, will I run into problems even though likes is already a ManyToMany foreignkey to Photo?

Comment: also! I believe it is auto_now_add :)

Comment: You will need to make sure that the model uses your existing table, possibly by renaming the existing table or using the `db_table` setting on the `Meta` class for your intermediary model.  Or by choosing your intermediary model's name appropriately.  And of course you'll have to add the database column yourself - syncdb won't do it because it's to be on an existing table.

Comment: thank you. I have Django South which will handle the column additions. I've edited my question and added my photo model in there for clarification. If you can, could you show me a more explicit answer so that I may accept and up vote your answer?